# How to login by using api in the app

Tags: android, postgresql, api

I want to develop an android app which will use api's for Login and then for fetching and posting data on Server . I want to use only web apis nothing else i have previously develop a app which uses PHP Mysql connectivity and Database was on Wamp Server. But now Database is PostGresql. Like:
1. I want to Login in the same way as on the Website by entring Serverurl as Username and Password by using api.
2. Fetching reports bu using api only

Answer (score 1):

You can code your backend server in [REST APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

You can follow [Basic HTTP Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) Mechanism for Authentication

As you said you have earlier developed REST APIs, I would suggest to use [Laravel PHP](http://laravel.com/) framework. Some good tutorials can be found [here](https://laracasts.com/).

Laravel supports REST and Basic HTTP Auth out-of the box.

Using Basic HTTP Auth with Laravel : [Doc Ref](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#http-basic-authentication)

If you are planning to make this app large, you can use [Dingo-API](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki)
It offers most of the REST API features inbuilt.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but im the starter here and can you please explain in detail or refer me any best  tutorial

Comment: and after coding in Rest Apis , suppose i have the particular api for login and another for fetching data, then what else i have to do in the app part

Comment: previously i have used 4 PHP files for the database connection like Config.php, and 3 more is this the same thing?

Comment: suppose i have the api like (abc.com/demo/reports) from whitch we can get the data in browser after the login page then how i can use it in android application. I already have the apis from whitch data has to be fetched, only thing to do is with the android part. what should i do in this case as i already have the api but only want to develop app using those apis?